# How to copy one class function variable value in another class window in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

this is the small part of source code of the project
i want to copy user variable from userlogin class to usermain class

tried to make a userlogin object in usermain class  but no working

```
from ftplib import parse150
import time
import sys
import sqlite3
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog,QApplication,QStackedWidget ,QMainWindow ,QWidget
conn =sqlite3.connect(r"C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\courier\\courier.db")
cur = conn.cursor()

class userlogin(QMainWindow):
    def _init_(self):
        super(userlogin,self)._init_()
        loadUi(r"C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\courier\\userlogin.ui",self)
        user = self.username.text()
        self.upass.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.login.clicked.connect(self.loginfunction)
        
    def loginfunction(self):
    \#---- WANT TO COPY THE USER VARIABLE IN USERMAIN CLASS----
        user = self.username.text()
        password = self.upass.text()

       

class usermain(QMainWindow):
        def _init_(self):
            super(usermain,self)._init_()
            loadUi(r"C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\courier\\usermain.ui",self)
\#--------COPY THE VALUE OF USER VARIABLE HERE

\#--------------main---------------------
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
welcome=welcomescreen()
widget = QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(welcome)
widget.setFixedHeight(750)
widget.setFixedWidth(1000)
widget.show()
try:
sys.exit(app.exec\_())
except:
conn.close()
print("existing")
```

Tried to derived class but not getting results

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please take your time to follow the [tour], read [ask], review the [checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648) and ensure that you provide a valid [mre]: right now your code is **not** reproducible (for instance, there's no declaration for `welcomescreen`). Also, be aware that adding QMainWindows or QDialogs to a QStackedWidget is highly discouraged (even if some tutorials tell you to do so): those are intended to be *top level widgets*, and should not be added as children as those **terrible** tutorials suggest.

Answer (score -2):

I think [signal/slot](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/signalsandslots.html) helps you, using signal and slot you can connect objects to each other and any value you want can transfer

Comment: @EhsanShivandi thank you for your reply but as a beginner I don't have any idea about signal/slot so can you explain it elaborately or can you edit the above code to make us understand what you're trying to say

Comment: I put the tutorial link, you can read this, you need to push yourself to learn from tutorials